# Filter output and set variable

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I would like to run a bash script which invokes a command and then sets a variable in the script with a part of the output from the first command. In my case I would like to set the variable `URL` to `https://loady-7jmiymbtlg-uc.a.run.app`.

`my-script.sh`:

```
gcloud run deploy loady

# echo $URL <--- how to set this with the output from the above command
```

When I run my script (example output):

```
karl@Karls-MacBook-Pro ~ $ ./my-script.sh
Deploying container to Cloud Run service [loady] in project [loady] region [us-central1]
✓ Deploying new service... Done.                                                               
  ✓ Creating Revision...                                                                       
  ✓ Routing traffic...                                                                         
  ✓ Setting IAM Policy...                                                                      
Done.                                                                                          
Service [loady] revision [loady-00001-nod] has been deployed and is serving 100 percent of traffic.
Service URL: https://loady-7jmiymbtlg-uc.a.run.app
```

So as you can see, the last line there.

Comment: You will involve bash tools like `grep`, `awk`, `sed` and many others to extract the output you desire, and set a variable containing the result. A oneliner of the form `URL=$( command | commands to manipulate the output)` could do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
URL=$(gcloud run deploy loady 2>&1 |grep -o -m1 "https://\S*")
```

The `2>&1` merges the stdout and stderr outputs of the `gcloud` command into stdout, needed for `|` to filter both through `grep` should that be necessary.

`grep` will output only (`-o`) the first (`-m1`) url matching the regular expression `https://\S*` (meaning `https://everything.until.before/next/space`).  The final stdout of the contents of `$()` is invisibly stored in `$URL`.

Since stderr isn't captured by `$()` or `|`, you can choose to still also display the output of the `gcloud` command by duplicating it all back to stderr with `tee`.

```
URL=$(gcloud run deploy loady 2>&1 |tee /dev/stderr |grep -o -m1 "https://\S*")
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation of what everything does, this should serve as good reference for future people who stumble upon this!